# How to check server response in if condition using angular and node

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular

I have created one registration form with angular and node. I wanted to show the sweetalert when data have inserted in database. I couldn't found the correct procedure to check server response status 200. Kindly find my code below.

In form.component.ts

```
onSubmit(data)
  {
    this.formDataservice.formData(data).subscribe(
      data => {
        if(data.status==200){
        Swal.fire({
          icon: 'success',
          title: 'Registration Successful!',
        })
      }
    },
      error => console.log(error)
    );
  }
```

In service

```
url ="http://localhost:3000/insertion";

constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

formData(data)
  {
    return this.http.post<any>(this.url,data, {observe: 'response'});
  }
```

In insertion.js using express

```
app.post('/insertion',function(request, response){
    response.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
    
    var name = request.body.name;
    var mobile = request.body.mobile;
    var email = request.body.email;
    var office = request.body.office;

    var sql = "INSERT INTO `Angular` (`name`,`mobile`,`email`,`office`) VALUES ('"+name+"','"+mobile+"','"+email+"','"+office+"')";

    database.query(sql,function(err,res){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            console.log("Data inserted!");  
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Currently your backend doesn't respond at all, the fact that it's an Angular app trying to consume it is irrelevant. Did you not test the endpoint? But also you shouldn't expose the whole response from the service, then the details of the transport layer are spreading across your whole app. Instead, think about what's useful to the UI - maybe expose an observable of Boolean success/failure instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to dispatch response from server.

```
app.post('/insertion',function(request, response){
    response.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
    
    var name = request.body.name;
    var mobile = request.body.mobile;
    var email = request.body.email;
    var office = request.body.office;

    var sql = "INSERT INTO `Angular` (`name`,`mobile`,`email`,`office`) VALUES ('"+name+"','"+mobile+"','"+email+"','"+office+"')";

    database.query(sql,function(err,res){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            response.status(500).json({
                           "error": "database error"
            })
        }else{
            console.log("Data inserted!");
            response.status(200).json({
                         "data" : "data inserted"
            })
        }
    });
});
```